# Converted VHD to VMDK but vmx missing

Tags: vmware-vmdk

I converted vhd to vmdk,  and with vmware worstation  tried to import the vmdk, but it says vmx is missing. when i did the conversion vmx file wasnt created. did i miss anything. i am aware vhd can be run in hyper-v, but my requirement is it run it on vmware workstation. Thanks

Comment: And how did you do this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

You can't import a vmdk directly. You have to make a new virtual machine and attach the vmdk as a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

VMDK is a HDD image - what you need is a descriptor for the VM itself... or you create one if possible.

Try creating a VM with comparable "hardware" (CPU, Memory ...) als select to not create a HDD but to use an existing... and select your VMDK.

But perhaps your migration tool (which one) supports migrating the VMX file too? 
What I used twiced in a running machine was the VMware converter.